# Python importlib.import_module() fails on the second execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

I'm trying to programmatically import functions in various folders, and I came across something weird that I can't figure out.

If I run this script once, it works. If I run it another time in the same console it fails. But I can run it by highlighting the code and pressing F9 as many times as I want, as long as it hasn't previously failed in the same console.

```
import os
import importlib
os.chdir('C:\\dev\\PRE2')

sec_name="P1"
algpath='./rating/RateTables/Section{sec_name}/Algorithms/'
algorithms = {}

for f in os.listdir(algpath.format(sec_name=sec_name)):
    algname, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    print(algname, ext)
    if ext=='.py':
        algorithms[algname] = importlib.import_module(
            f'rating.RateTables.Section{sec_name}.Algorithms.{algname}',
            f'rating.RateTables.Section{sec_name}.Algorithms.{algname}.{algname}')
```

I'm using a standalone version of Spyder with python 3.8.10 on Windows.

My file structure:

```
/PRE2
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    /rating
         __init__.py
         section.py
         rate.py
         /RateTables
             /SectionP1
             /SectionP2
             /SectionP3
                 /Algorithms
                     algo1.py
                     algo2.py
                     algoXYZ.py
```

Here's the traceback:

```
File h:\scripts\importlib_test.py:27
    algorithms[algname] = importlib.import_module(
  File importlib\__init__.py:127 in import_module

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014 in _gcd_import

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991 in _find_and_load

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:971 in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:914 in _find_spec

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1407 in find_spec

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1373 in _get_spec

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1239 in __iter__

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1227 in _recalculate

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1239 in __iter__

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1227 in _recalculate

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1239 in __iter__

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1227 in _recalculate

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1223 in _get_parent_path

KeyError: 'rating'
```

I've looked at other related questions, but I can't seem to figure out why the code would fail on the second execution. Any help would be appreciated.